# xunit IClassFixture without constructor

Tags: c#, xunit

I have the following simplified pseudocode

```
class CommonSetup
{
    public void CommonSetup()
    {
         // do stuff once per class
    }

    public void Foo() { }
}

abstract class BaseTest : IClassFixture<CommonSetup>
{
    public void BaseTest(CommonSetup setup)
    {
        setup.Foo();
    }
}

class MyTest : BaseTest
{
     // i dont want to have a ctor here
}
```

I need access to `CommonSetup` from `BaseTest` but I don't want `MyTest` to have a constructor in order to pass `CommonSetup` through to it because it's pointless boilerplate noise.

Is there a different syntax/mechanism for achieving the same as `IClassFixture<>` without the need to use constructors to pass the the `CommonSetup` around?

Answer (score 0):

In my view, it is possible to create a static field to avoid of creation a new object and to share instance across all derived classes.

So let me show an example:

```
class CommonSetup
{
    public CommonSetup()
    {
        // do stuff once per class
    }

    public void Foo() { }
}
```

and:

```
abstract class BaseTest : IClassFixture<CommonSetup>
{
    protected static CommonSetup _commonSetup = new CommonSetup();

    public BaseTest()
    {
        _commonSetup.Foo();
    }
}
```

and your derived classes will not want to have constructor to send parameters for `BaseTest` class:

```
class MyTest : BaseTest
{
    // There is no need to have constructor to initialize `BaseTest` constructor
}
```